# How is it possible that Poisson GLM accepts non-integer numbers?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I am really stunned by the fact that the Poisson GLM accepts non-integer numbers! Look:

Data (contents of `data.txt`):

```
1   2001    0.25  1
1   2002    0.5   1
1   2003    1     1
2   2001    0.25  1
2   2002    0.5   1
2   2003    1     1
```

R script:

```
t        <- read.table("data.txt")
names(t) <- c('site', 'year', 'count', 'weight')
tm       <- glm(count ~ 0 + as.factor(site) + as.factor(year), data = t, 
                family = "quasipoisson")  # also works with family="poisson"
years    <- 2001:2003
plot(years, exp(c(0, tail(coef(tm), length(years)-1))), type = "l")
```

The resultant year index is as "expected", i.e., `1-2-4` in years `2001-2003`.

**But how is it possible that Poisson GLM takes non-integer numbers? The Poisson distribution has always been integer-only!**

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly do you want to know? How the fitting algorithm deals with non-integers? Or why R does not check whether the response is an integer? Or whether anything is wrong in the result when non-integers are supplied?

Comment: @Momo, yes, all these questions are interesting!

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that. You're more likely to get a good answer this way.

Comment: Not that this really matters, as it's true for `family="poisson"` as well, but note that your example isn't a Poisson GLM, as you're using the `quasipoisson` family, which only depends on the relationship between the mean and the variance anyway, so in that case, there should be no surprise about taking non-integer numbers.

Comment: Here are [some references](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38588/7071) on why this might make sense.

Answer (score 20):

Of course you are correct that the Poisson distribution technically is defined only for integers.  However, statistical modeling is the art of good approximations ("[all models are wrong](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57407/what-is-the-meaning-of-all-models-are-wrong-but-some-are-useful)"), and there are times when it makes sense to treat non-integer data as though it were [approximately] Poisson.

For example, if you send out two observers to record the same count data, it may happen that the two observers do not always agree on the count -- one might say that something happened 3 times while the other said it happened 4 times.  It is nice then to have the option to use 3.5 when fitting your Poisson coefficients, instead of having to choose between 3 and 4.

Computationally, the factorial in the Poisson could make it seem difficult to work with non-integers, but a [continuous generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) of the factorial exists.  Moreover, performing maximum likelihood estimation for the Poisson does not even involve the factorial function, [once you simplify the expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression#Maximum_likelihood-based_parameter_estimation).

Answer (score 16):

For a response $y$, if you assume the logarithm of its expectation is a linear combination of predictors $\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}\vec{x}$
$$\operatorname{E}Y_i=\exp{\vec\beta^{\mathrm{T}}\vec{x}_i}$$
then consistent estimates for the regression coefficients $\vec\beta$ can be obtained by solving the score equations for the Poisson model:
$$\sum_i^n{\vec{x}_i\left(y_i-\exp{\vec\beta^{\mathrm{T}}\vec{x}_i}\right)}=0$$
Of course consistency doesn't imply validity of any tests or confidence intervals; the likelihood has not been specified.

This follows on from the method-of-moments approach we learnt at school, & leads on to that of [generalized estimating equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation).

@Aaron's pointed out you're actually using a quasi-Poisson fit in your code. That means the variance is proportional to the mean

$$\operatorname{Var}Y_i=\phi\operatorname{E}Y_i$$

with a dispersion parameter $\phi$ that can be estimated from the data. The coefficient estimates will be the same, but their standard errors wider; this is a more flexible & therefore more generally useful approach. (Note also that sandwich estimators for the parameters' variance–covariance matrix are often used in these sort of situations to give robust standard errors.)