# Support of distribution (distribution fitting)

Tags: distributions, matlab, fitting, parameterization

This might be a weird question. I want to know why Matlab still run to produce estimated parameter whenever I input data which doesn't belong to the support of the distribution?

E.g.

[image]

I want to know the idea behind it.Thanks!!

Comment: But Matlab gives you error messages indicating precisely that the input does not belong to the support...

Comment: Look at the second fit, Poissfit (0.5). The support for poisson distribution is  integer which is greater or equal zero.

Comment: Perhaps there exists a generalized version of Poisson distribution the support of which includes 0.5? See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858161/does-the-poisson-distribution-work-for-non-integer-exponents) thread. Also, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70054/how-is-it-possible-that-poisson-glm-accepts-non-integer-numbers) is a relevant thread. Finally, there is some discussion [here](http://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/6412).