# Why one can fit Poisson GLM on non-integer values in Stata?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution

I have aggregated death counts and some categorical predictors e.g. era, drug use, and I'm running a Poisson GZLM in SPSS, also a `glm` in Stata (generalized linear model). There are many, but not excessive, zeros and it has been suggested to me to add 0.5 to the observed values. When I do that the GENLIN procedure in SPSS won't run, because the Poisson dependent should have integer values. However, the `glm` with family Poisson and log link in Stata runs and just makes a note that the dependent has non-integer values.

Why does Stata run the Poisson `glm` if the values of the dependent should be integers only?

Comment: When you say there are many zeroes - are there more than would be expected for a Poisson model? Or is it just that the Poisson mean is quite small?

Comment: Just adding 0.5 strikes me as a fudge at best; do you have literature or theoretical support for that?

Comment: Some [useful references](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38588/7071) on the why.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons why this feature of `glm` is useful is the possibility to perform quasi-maximum likelihood estimations. I cannot be be sure if this was originally the main purpose for not restricting the admissible domain of the dependent variable, but it gives you a good example of a setting where this is very useful.

See, as a similar case, the fractional regression, where the dependent variable is continuous in [0,1] instead of binary but the link function is often chosen to be a normal cdf or a logistic function. As long as the likelihood belongs to the linear exponential family and the range of variation of the dependent variable is the same, the parameters of the conditional mean are consistently estimated (even if the distribution of the dependent variable is misspecified; see GMT(1984)).

The command `fracreg [logit|probit]` has been around for a while now and performs this estimation, but an alternative  is just `glm y X, link(logit) family(binomial) vce(robust)` (and when Papke & Wooldridge (1996) was published the only way in Stata; see Baum(2008)). In both cases the estimation is by quasi-maximum likelihood.

See also at the [link](http://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/) that Nick Cox posted in a comment above:
"It turns out that the estimated coefficients of the maximum-likelihood Poisson estimator in no way depend on the assumption that E(yj) = Var(yj), so even if the assumption is violated, the estimates of the coefficients b0, b1, …, bk are unaffected." That's exactly what I am talking about.

References:

[Baum (2008) Stata Tip 63: Modeling Proportions, The Stata Journal](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0147)

[Goriereux, Monfort, Trognon (1984), Pseudo Maximum Likelihood Methods: Theory](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM8sW9_onWAhWILlAKHcGZC5EQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstor.org%2Fstable%2F1913471&usg=AFQjCNHFJG5kbo5S9UDOJ3NyryuRYGHbZw)

[Papke, Wooldridge (1996), Econometric Methods for Fractional Response Variables With an Application to 401 (K) Plan Participation Rates](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP9-fD_onWAhXNJFAKHbFQDlcQFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstor.org%2Fstable%2F2285155&usg=AFQjCNECrrPjQr_TxR5jo6aDr4R9zBHVWw)

Answer (score 1):

You can fit a Poisson model to any kind of data. But it doesn't really make sense to fit it to data that have non-integers, because it's supposed to be counts.

SPSS is worrying about that. Stata isn't.

Have you tested to see if you do have too many zeroes?  (I *always* do.)  If you do, you should run negative binomial regression instead.  In Stata, run:

```
estat gof
```

after a Poisson regression to get a test of goodness of fit.

(Just as an aside, it's the opposite way around with non-integer frequency weights, Stata won't allow them, SPSS will.)

Comment: If you think there are too many zeros, you may want to run a zero-inflated Poisson (zip) model, instead of negative binomial, which is more for overdispersion.

Comment: More precisely, `SPSS` is worrying about enough to not let the model run, while 'Stata` is telling the user it's a problem but letting the user deal with that.  Also, as @gung points out, for too many zeroes, a ZIP model seems more apropos; for overdispersion, negative binomial; for both - ZINB.

Comment: The view that Poisson regression is for counts only is widely rebutted: for one informal account with Stata flavour see http://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/ Also, for Stata "non-integer frequency weights" just can't be frequency weights, but they can be analytic weights.

Comment: Stata commands relevant (here names are self-explanatory): `zip`, `zinb`, `nbreg`.

Comment: Here's a [simulation paper](http://personal.lse.ac.uk/TENREYRO/ppml-fsr.pdf) where the Poisson quasi-MLE does very well when there are lots of zeros.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm running the regressions for the two genders separately. In males the frequency of zeros is 11%, in the females 35%. Adding .5 was suggested to me because when I run the model with up to 3-way interactions in the se s of the estimates for the 2-way interaction terms are larger than the se s of the respective 2-way interaction terms when the model is run with only up to 2-way interactions in. I thought that was to be expected, but to the person who pointed it out it seemed odd because it happens when the higher-order interaction term is significant but also when it is not.

Comment: I should add that this is preliminary data and we're exploring, plus we're not expecting a good fit as the predictors are 6 but we're only fitting up to 3-way interactions. Also, estat gof does not run after glm. I am not running Poisson regression as such (ie poisson), I am running a Poisson under a generalized linear model (ie glm).